# Insert a Text file as Blob data into SQLite Database

Tags: java, android

I created a db in sqlite with a table USER_DETAILS(USER_ID varchar,USER_NAME varchar,USER_INFO blob).I tried creating a file convert it into a byteArray and store it as a blob in the table.The db and the table got created but not the values. Here is my code .Can somebody pl guide on how to insert the blob data into the table?

create file :`String fileNameDb = fileName + mTextDocNo++;

```
        FileOutputStream fis = (FileOutputStream) openFileOutput(
                fileNameDb, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        System.out.println("Create File " + fis);

        byte[] textFileArray = new byte[1024];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < textFileArray.length) {
            fis.write(textFileArray);
        }
        System.out.println("Created the byteArray " + textFileArray);

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
        oos.writeChars(inputData);

        System.out.println("Calling the createNoteMethod------------>>>");
        mDbHelper.createNote(fileNameDb, inputData + fileNameDb,
                textFileArray);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        fis.close();
```

Insert stmt method :

```
stmt = mDb.compileStatement("INSERT INTO USER_DETAILS VALUES(?,?,?)");
stmt.bindString(1, user_id);
stmt.bindString(2, user_name);
stmt.bindBlob(3, user_info);
stmt.executeInsert();
```

I get the below exception when i try creating the byteArray

> 03-14 17:07:07.674: WARN/System.err(613): java.io.IOException: No space left on device
>   03-14 
>   17:07:07.694: WARN/System.err(613):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.write(Native Method)

03-14 17:07:07.704: WARN/System.err(613):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.write(BlockGuard.java:171)

03-14 17:07:07.704: WARN/System.err(613):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:300)

03-14 17:07:07.715: WARN/System.err(613):     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:256)

03-14 17:07:07.715: WARN/System.err(613):     at com.example.FileSharing.FileSharingActivity.createFile(FileSharingActivity.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

You have ***many*** problems with your code:

- You are opening a file output stream but your variable name is
  misleading (`fis`)
- You then write an empty array out to this stream, 1024 times
- You then create an `ObjectOutputStream`, chain it to the
  `FileOutputStream` and write out some random object which the
  definition of is not shown in your code sample.
- You invoke a method prior to closing your streams, this is a
  potential bug especially if you are (I wager a guess), reopening the
  streams in the method and performing operations on them.
- The second parameter to your `mDbHelper` method, did you really
  intend on concatenating your input object with the output file name?

Fix all those errors, then edit your question if you still have problems after that.